# posição da div fixed em baixo de outras divs

Tags: html, css

Ola

eu gostaria de colocar uma div fixed do lado direito da minha div sem que fique por cima dos bonecos.

a medida que vou dando scroll essa div vai acompanhando o scroll mas apenas dentro da div preta! os bonecos sao criados automaticamente com base no numero de casos dentro da DB e gostava que a div fixed nao interferi-se com os bonecos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
#images {
    margin: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }

#imagess {
    margin: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }

.bordadocontador {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 2px solid #ffff00;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 7px 12px 7px 12px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    float: right;
   }
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 direita">
    <h3> Numero de vítimas </h3>

    <div id="images"></div>
    <div id="imagess"></div>

    <div class="bordadocontador">
      <div id="contadordebonecos"></div>bla bla bla
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: De modo geral, elementos com `position:fixed` não respeitam seu elemento pai. Ele é guiado pela janela ou documento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc tem que avaliar como é sua situação ai, mas vc pode trocar o `position:fixed` por `position:sticky`, como isso o elemento fica fixo relativo ao pai e aceita o `float` etc, e não relativo a janela como um todo...

Repare que eu coloquei uma borda preta no `col-`, pois ela tem apenas a altura do próprio conteúdo, e quando vc faz o `scroll` ela pode ou não sair da tela, por isso falei que vc tem que estudar seu caso. De qq forma com o `position:sticky` vc pode chegar a uma solução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria bom vc tirar uma horinha para estudar os `positions` do CSS, entendendo como eles funcionam vai te ajudar muito a montar layouts. No seu caso esses `position:absolutes` ao meu ver são desnecessários e podem acabar mais atrapalhando do que ajudando, pense nisso https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
 <style>
  html,
  body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   /* background-color: black; */
  }

  body {
   height: 150vh;
  }

  #images {
   margin: 4px;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
  }

  #imagess {
   margin: 4px;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
  }

  .bordadocontador {
   color: white;
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 2px solid #ffff00;
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 7px 12px 7px 12px;
   position: sticky;
   z-index: 3;
   float: right;
   top: 100px;
  }
  .teste {
   position: sticky;
   top: 100px;
   margin-top: 200px;
  }
  .direita {
   border: 1px solid #000;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 direita">
   <h3> Numero de vítimas </h3>
 
   <div id="images">
    <img src="https://placecage.com/51/100">
   </div>
   <div id="imagess">
    <img src="https://placecage.com/50/100">
   </div>
 
   <div class="bordadocontador">
    <div id="contadordebonecos"></div>bla bla bla
   </div>
 
   <div class="teste">123</div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar: 
position: fixed; 
right: 0; 
top: 100px;

Comment: Só uma dica, com right:0 e positin:fixed o elemento vai ficar colado na direita da janela do browser, e não colado na direita do elemento no qual está dentro

Comment: Sim, com o que eu postei o elemento vai ficar mais estatico. Caso a div dos bonecos aumentar, elas ficarão sobrepostas.